# how to send sms with both ascii and unicode in android programmatically

Tags: android

My code for inserting message in android :

```
values.put("address","1234");

values.put("body","रु27=रु27 फुल टॉकटाइम, असीमित वैधता के साथ। पाएं रु21.3 तुरंत, शेष टॉकटाइम 1 घंटे में। ऑफर एयरटेल रिटेलर द्वारा 8-Jul-15 तक।");

getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

But it fails

Please help me to send sms containing both  unicode and ascii characters.

Comment: what's the outcome.any error or exception or anything else.

Comment: is any other way to doing this?

Comment: please post the exception

Comment: it insert only address wit out  message body